# How does hibernate fire query?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have one-to-one hibernate annotation mapping. like for eg.

```
     @Entity
     @Table(name="person")
     class Person{
       @OneToOne( mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
       private Passport passport;
       ......
     }

     @Entity
     @Table(name="passport")
     class Passport{
     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "statusid")
     private Person person;
     ......
     .....
     }
```

Here `Person` is owned and `Passport` is owner. When I perform `select` operation on `person` then why is hibernate firing two queries i.e. select from `person` and `passport`.
According to hibernate documentation

```
the owner is responsible for the association column(s) update
```

Answer (score 0):

Concept of relationship's owner is not connected to your issue. As also excerpt you took from documentation hints, owning side is consulted when persisting relationship. It does not mean that other side of relationship is lazily loaded.

What you would need for your use case is lazy loading of one-to-one relationship. Unfortunately Hibernate does not support it. Typical hack to get around this limitation is to define relationship that is one-to-one on the one side and one-to-many (lazy) on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Two queries are fired because of the -cascad all field you have added
(In one to one mapping)
what hibernate does here . .It brings data of all the referencing fields with it.

1-Suppose you select one person with id=3;

2-then you will have a method with following syntax in your dao layer

Person finbyid(Integer personid)
{
.........
........
return person;
}

3-and  corresponding sql query will be something like

select * from Person where id=3;

4-  hibernate here does one more thing-

it brings all passport objects associated with it also.

so you can do
Passport pass=person.getPassport();

and now pass object of Passport will have all column No seperate query will be fired now. .
 you can directly use
pass.getPassportid();
pass.getPassportnumber();

etc. .
hope you doubt is cleared